# Column Summations in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

Our environment is z/OS DB2.
I have the below data in a table.

```
     Year     Amount

     1998      2000
     1999      3000
     2000      2500
     2001     10000
```

Using SQL Query I want the result as shown below.
The result should be as follows:

```
     Year     Amount    Total_Amount_Invested

     1998      2000        2000
     1999      3000        5000
     2000      2500        7500
     2001     10000       17500
```

Appreciate your help in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called running total calculation.
I have created one dummy functionlity you can check this I hope that you will get some idea from this.

```
create table Test
(
    year int,
    amount int
)

insert into Test (year,amount)
values
(1998,2000),
(1999,3000),
(2000,2500),
(2001,10000)

select 
    t1.year,
    sum(t2.amount) 
from 
    Test t1
    join test t2
    ON T2.year <= T1.year
group by
T1.year
```

**I have concidered Year to calculate your sum if you want you can do it by using your primary key**

You can also check with sql fiddle 
this is the DEMO I have created.
[DEMO Click to see](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df70f/1)

Comment: @Shiva Komuravelly Please tell wheather my query helpd you or not

Comment: Yes it did and I have used it.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use [OLAP functions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_olapspecification.dita):

```
declare global temporary table session.test (
     year int
    ,amount int
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

insert into session.test (year,amount)
    SELECT 1998,2000  FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1999,3000  FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2000,2500  FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2001,10000 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
;

SELECT 
     year
    ,sumamt
    ,sum(sumamt) OVER (ORDER BY year ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM (
    select 
         year
        ,sum(amount) AS SUMAMT
    from session.test t1
    GROUP BY year
) A
;
```